# Splitting python dataframe dynamically into subsets

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an excel file in this format and am trying to create a parser that reads the file and structures the data

[image]

I have read it into Python and it looks like this:
[image]

I want to split the dataframe by scenarios and am now trying to split the dataframe based on non-null values from the Scenario column, but have not managed to figure it out.

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_fp,sheet_name=test, header=None)
df.rename(columns=df.columns[0]: 'Scenario'}, inplace=True)
df.dropna(how='all')

#splitted_dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['Scenario'].notna)]
```

Comment: Share your code so far.

Comment: Post a small sample dataframe that people can work with. Ideally, you'll include your first attempt at a solution.